# When aiming to AOT compile a ruby script with MacRuby is there any restriction on the language?

Tags: ruby, macos, macruby, aot

I am looking into using MacRuby and am interested in it's ability to AOT compile ruby code down to an executable. I am wondering though whether this places a restriction on the code in any way? Is there a subset of ruby which is supported or can i go ahead and perform all the meta-magic i want and still have the code AOT compiled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Laurent Sansonetti of apple fame:

Yes, the AOT compiler should fully support the Ruby language. If you
find something that does not work when compiled, it's a bug :) Please
report them and we will fix them.